# Continuous pairing request from a smart watch

Tags: bluetooth, android-wear

Some time ago I replaced a phone to a new one using Android 7 (before it was 6) and my smart watch updated to Android Wear 2.0. Hard to tell what was the reason but since then each time a bluetooth connection between the devices is broken and going to be re-established there is a pairing request with a code which needs to be confirmed on both devices. Is there a way to make a phone and a watch to trust each other once and forever and to connect without re-asking a confirmation? This was the case with Android 6/Android Wear 1.1.

Not sure it matters, but the phone is 
Asus ZenFone AR and the watch: Casio WSD-F10.

Comment: What phone and what watch is it? They should only need to pair once so it sounds like a software problem in one or other device. Please [edit] your question to say what, so perhaps someone with the same combination can find your question and help.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue across most Android wear devices, Wear 2.0 and any watch.
You'll see this issue all over the Internet.
I have two Moto 360's and both constantly have pair requests with my Android 7 Motorola Droid 2.
I have factory reset both, followed Google's directions and still does it.
Hopefully Wear OS 3.0 will fix it, but I've heard both of my watches are not getting that update, which is BS.